# Form border and topic blinks when setting focus programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, focus, windows-10

I have application that is normally hidden, but I want it to gain focus when I move mouse cursor to specific location on screen.

I have tried following code to activate the form:

```
this.Show();
this.BringToFront();
this.Focus();
this.Activate();
```

Also tried to add this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

SetForegroundWindow(this.Handle);
```

Whatever I do, my application is not stealing focus from currently active application, but only blinks itself without gaining focus.

Is there any other methods to force form to foreground and focused?

Comment: Maybe ugly, but try calling *this.TopMost = true;* and then *this.TopMost = false;* directly after comes to my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try several things and choose the one that suits you.
This one should always bring the form to the front.

```
this.TopMost = true;
this.ShowDialog();
```

You can also try :

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
this.Show();
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```

Also:

```
this.BringToFront();
```

Comment: Thanks! First minimize, then opacity to 0 (to avoid animation when un-minimize), then show, then normal size, and finally opacity back to 1. Ugly, but it works.